# Can the codec of TiDB guarantee that the UTF-8 string is memcomparable?

Tags: utf-8, tidb

Is there any coding suggestion if our key needs to support UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

The character sets of TiDB use UTF-8 by default and currently only support UTF-8.

The string of TiDB uses the memcomparable format.